# Mimicking the `proof` environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I want to mimic the `proof` environment from the `amsthm` package.

I want something that has the same layout (margins, etc.) as the `proof` environment, but with the following changes:

1) Instead of beginning with *Proof.*, I want it to begin with *Proof outline.*

2) I don't want a white box added at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
Here is introductory text.
\begin{proof}
Here is text in the proof.
\end{proof}
Here is concluding text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this just by patching in a few optional commands to the `proof` environment itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newenvironment{proofoutline}
 {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{}\proof[Proof outline]}
 {\endproof}
\begin{document}

\begin{proofoutline}
 This is not a proof.
\end{proofoutline}

\end{document}
```